# Port Numbers in IPv4 & IPv6 is 16bits unsigned binary number so, each one is in range of 1 to 65535 (0 is reserved)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp, port

We all know that Port numbers in IPv4 and IPv6 are 16 bits wide so the range should be 0 to 65535, But I have heard that 0 is excluded and reserved for something else, This range is now 1 to 65535.

I want to know for what purpose it is reserved and for what purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port 0 is used as a "wildcard" port, meaning that when an application tries to create a socket and `bind()` it to an IP address, and supplies 0 as the port, the OS automatically binds the socket to a random available ephemeral port.

This is useful when applications need to send data and do not care which port it is sent from.  This ensures that applications do not need to constantly try to find a suitable port manually.

The OS is powerful, so let it do (some of) the work for you.

Comment: Binding to port 0 is not limited to just TCP, UDP can use it, too. It is also not limited to just senders, there are valid cases where a listener may want to use a random port, too. Binding to port 0 allows the OS to bind to a random available [*ephemeral* port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.lifewire.com/port-0-in-tcp-and-udp-818145):

> Port 0 is a wildcard port that tells the system to find a suitable port number.

Comment: what do you mean by `wildcard`?